# Is this probability always $1$?

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a random variable, uniformly distributed in the interval $(0,1)$. Compute $P(X(1-X) < \frac14)$.

Attempt:$$P(X(1-X)<\tfrac14)=P(X-X^2<\tfrac14)=P(X^2-X+\tfrac14>0)=P((X-\tfrac12)^2>0)$$

Isn't this always $1$ though? I guess it's a trick question? (Because the rest of the problems basically steer you towards working with the density functions)

Comment: Just note $P[X = 1/2] = 0$ because $X \sim U(0, 1)$.  Hence $1 = P[(X - 1/2)^2 \geq 0] = P[(X - 1/2)^2 > 0] + P[X = 1/2]$ implies $P[(X - 1/2)^2 > 0] = 1$.